# What features should I look for in a small wooden shed for tool storage?

Tags: tools, storage

I live in Cambridge, England and I would like to buy a small wooden shed (about 4 meters square) to store my tools and a freezer but as I never bought one before I don't know the important features. I saw wall thickness of 12 millimeters and 14 millimeters but I don't know if it's enough or not to resist the wind.

Which other features are important? Are wooden sheds better than metal sheds?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Things I know about sheds ...

- Sheds need a proper base.
- Things stored in them will rust (your freezer will too).
- Sheds need a proper base.
- Wooden sheds have an expected lifetime of about 10 years.
- Sheds need a proper base.
- Sheds blowing down isn't a big problem for sheds in typical UK gardens.
- Sheds need a proper base.
- Wooden sheds are probably easiest to hammer nails into.
- Sheds need a proper base.
- You will want to hammer nails into your shed. Things hang on nails.
- The floor will rot because your lawnmower drips water onto it.
- Sheds last longer if carefully maintained.
- You will neglect your shed and it will gradually collapse.
- All sheds are too small because you fill them with precious stuff that metamorphoses into
  unidentifiable junk.

A good way to decide on sheds is to look at ones that have been standing on display in garden-centres for a few years. Look for broken handles, misaligned doors, water stains etc.

Comment: And they need a proper base :-)  Seriously, though, I have to agree with that.  Otherwise the walls will shift and crack over time and you will be unhappy.  Don't expect it to just hold itself together as a cube.  If it is on uneven footing, it will sag and then your door won't shut right, and so on.